# Create a new role with RoleManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

I created a context (with scaffolding) and also a user.
I also set to play the db (and created a migration).
This works perfectly!
I would now just like to create a role and then assign it to a user.

For that, I modified my startup.cs file in order to proceed (I was not able to find a tutorial that shows how to create / assign a role with a different context than that of ApplicationDbContext).

I'm happy with the error in my code (at least I think), but I do not know how to handle it and what to replace the object.

So I created a CreateRoles method that receives a serviceProvider (of type IServiceProvider) and in this method I try to initialize the romes and then assign them to the different users of my db.

My concern is here (I think):

> var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService > ();

Indeed,  is I think used for the ApplicationDbContext except that I use jakformulaireContext.

My question is: what should I replace  (if that's what I need to replace)?

Let me know if you need mode info or mode code!

**Startup Class**

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddDbContext<jakformulaireContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("jakformulaireContextConnection")));
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<jakformulaireUser>(configg =>
    {
        configg.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<jakformulaireContext>(); ;


    var config = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
    });
    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    services.AddSingleton(mapper);

    //services.AddAutoMapper();
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

    services.AddSession();

    // requires
    // using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
    // using WebPWrecover.Services;
    services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
    services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);

    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials());
    });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseSession();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    //CreateRoles(serviceProvider).Wait();
}

private async Task CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    //initializing custom roles   
    var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
    var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<jakformulaireUser>>();
    string[] roleNames = { "Guest", "Member", "Admin" };
    IdentityResult roleResult;

    foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
    {
        var roleExist = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
        if (!roleExist)
        {
            //create the roles and seed them to the database: Question 1  
            roleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
        }
    }

    jakformulaireUser user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync("test@test.com");

    if (user == null)
    {
        user = new jakformulaireUser()
        {
            UserName = "test@test.com",
            Email = "test@test.com",
            EmailConfirmed = true
        };
        await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, "Test123$");
    }
    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Member");


    jakformulaireUser user1 = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync("test@live.be");

    if (user1 == null)
    {
        user1 = new jakformulaireUser()
        {
            UserName = "test@live.be",
            Email = "test@live.be",
            EmailConfirmed = true
        };
        await UserManager.CreateAsync(user1, "Test123$");
    }
    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user1, "Admin");

}
```

}

**Context**

```
public class jakformulaireContext : IdentityDbContext<jakformulaireUser>
{
    public jakformulaireContext(DbContextOptions<jakformulaireContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error message? Is it the one from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53776469/trying-to-create-roles-while-scaffolding)?

Comment: Can I see your startup class?

Comment: @Kirk Yep it is the same error

Comment: @Soheil ill post it tommorow, i dont have my computer atm

Comment: @Korpin Did you custom your context by `class  jakformulaireContext : IdentityDbContext<YourAppUser, YourIdentityRole>` ? If so,make sure anywhere you use the `RoleManager<IdentityRole>` service and the `UserManager<>` service should be replaced with `RoleManager< YourIdentityRole>` and `UserManager<YourAppUser>`

Comment: @itminus i've edited my code, the thing is i don't have a jakformulaireRole, i don't know how to create one? Isn't automatic with the context and the user?

Comment: @Korpin try `services.AddIdentity<jakformulaireUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()`

Comment: I receive an error "InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Identity.Application
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationOptions.AddScheme(string name, Action<AuthenticationSchemeBuilder> configureBuilder)"

Comment: How did you register  `services.AddIdentity<jakformulaireUser, IdentityRole>() .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()` ? I mean you need replace the old `services.AddDefaultIdentity<jakformulaireUser>(configg =>
    {
        configg.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<jakformulaireContext>(); ;`

Comment: @Korpin the complete code :  `services.AddIdentity<jakformulaireUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
        .AddDefaultUI()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<jakformulaireContext>()`

Comment: Okey, with the second one i could manage to open my application! And it was able to enter in CreateRoles method and create the roles and users! Thx man, you totally covered my question! If you want do not hesitate to post it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs typically when you create your own `IdentityRole` or when you forget to register the `RoleManager`.

1. If you have customed the context by `class jakformulaireContext : IdentityDbContext<YourAppUser, YourIdentityRole>`, **make sure anywhere you use the `RoleManager<IdentityRole>` service has be replaced with `RoleManager< YourIdentityRole>`**
2. Also, **make sure the `RoleManager<YourIdentityRole>` has been registered** . If you don't create your own version of `IdentityRole`, simply call `.AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()`

   ```
    services.AddIdentity<jakformulaireUser, IdentityRole>() 
       .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()  // make sure the roleManager has been registered .
       .AddDefaultUI() 
       // other features ....
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<jakformulaireContext>()
   ```